# Create new group from specific title and group

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm really bad at LDAP so I don't really know where to start.

Is it possible to make a new distrubution or security group with users from another group that has a specific Title? There are too many users to add them manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to know how you want to interact with AD -- writing a program (language?) or using an LDAP client (which one?). I'll provide info on using ldifde.exe from the remote server administration tools. To get a list of DNs that are in another group *and* have a specific title, use a filter with the title and membership requirement

```
ldifde -f output.txt -r "(&(title=Desired Title)(memberOf=cn=GroupName,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com))" -l "NULL"
```

This returns user records that are direct members of the specified group (you'll need the fully qualified LDAP DN of the group, wildcards are not supported for memberOf -- the example is a group named "GroupName" in an OU called "Groups" at the root of the example.com AD).

Then you need to create a new group with the identified user DNs as members. The output.txt file will have a lot of lines that say "changetype: add\n\n" ... get rid of those so you've just got DNs. Change the "dn: " to "member: ". Prepend the following information to the list of group members to create an LDIF file to create a new global security group:

```
dn: CN=GroupName,OU=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: add
objectClass: group
cn: GroupName
distinguishedName: CN=GroupName,OU=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
instanceType: 4
name: GroupName
sAMAccountName: GroupName
groupType: -2147483646
objectCategory: CN=Group,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,dc=example,dc=com
member: CN=Person1,OU=ResourceUsers,dc=example,dc=com
member: CN=Person2,OU=ResourceUsers,dc=example,dc=com
member: CN=Person3,OU=ResourceUsers,dc=example,dc=com
member: CN=Person4,OU=ResourceUsers,dc=example,dc=com
member: CN=Person5,OU=ResourceUsers,dc=example,dc=com
```

Import the LDIF file using:

```
ldifde -i -v -k -y -f output.txt
```

The group will be created & populated with the accounts listed in the "member" attribute.

This doesn't do anything if you add a new person to the first group with the desired title -- this is a one-time snapshot. You can easily identify people who should be added/removed from the second group

Need to be added -- anyone with desired title who is a member of SourceGroupName but not a member of CreatedGroupName:

```
(&(title=Desired Title)(memberOf=cn=SourceGroupName,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com)(!(memberOf=cn=CreatedGroupName,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com)))
```

Need to be removed -- anyone who is a member of CreatedGroupName who is not a member of SourceGroupName or does not have the desired title.

```
(&(memberOf=cn=CreatedGroupName,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com)(|(!(title=Desired Title))(!(memberOf=cn=SourceGroupName,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com))))
```

Add/remove members from the new group as individuals match one of these two filters.